# How to split excell cell into Multiple Column based on Heading Tag?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to split excel cells based on Heading. But, failed. Is there any VBA or formula to split or separate into multiple columns?

I want to separate like below system:

**Main Text | Heading 2 | Heading 3 | Heading 4 | Heading 5**

I tried to split the cell by section. But failed. I used the Kutools excell addon. But not working. Screenshot attached.

[image: Kutools split text not working]

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec
> placerat mollis urna, quis aliquam orci luctus nec.
>
> == Heading 2: Plot ==
>
> Sed rutrum luctus lorem. Donec nibh mi, laoreet vel lectus a, viverra
> egestas diam. Vestibulum eget tortor est. Mauris magna enim, laoreet a
> efficitur et, scelerisque nec felis.
>
> === Heading 3 : Cast ===
>
> Nulla nec commodo tellus. Aliquam sed diam sollicitudin, tempor ex id,
> dignissim sem. Morbi mauris augue, congue id blandit in, rutrum quis
> sapien.
>
> ==== Heading 4 : Review ====
>
> Ut commodo tellus ut lectus convallis pretium. Nunc elit massa,
> dignissim non orci et, vehicula gravida enim. Etiam euismod arcu sed
> quam faucibus mattis. Nam maximus velit et eleifend dapibus.
>
> ===== Heading 5 : Links =====
>
> Proin porttitor quis turpis ac fermentum. Suspendisse eget urna arcu.
> Pellentesque viverra enim velit, et mollis enim eleifend non.
> Pellentesque eget dapibus dolor. Etiam vitae neque ut nunc egestas
> rutrum.

Comment: No, there is no ready-made code for your specific situation. If you tried, post what you tried, then explain where you got stuck.

Comment: @teylyn I tried to split the cell by section. But failed. I used Kutools excell addon. :( Please, check the result. https://prnt.sc/rubfbh

Comment: @teylyn, at the beginning, is the text in the Sheet in one single cell please?

Comment: As @teylyn said, this is a programming Forum, so you should at least try some code and tell us where you failed so we could assist you

Comment: power query does this very quickly. Let's try it

Comment: @TsiriniainaRakotonirina, Yah.. the text is in a single cell..

Comment: @TsiriniainaRakotonirina brother, I tried this formula-
=LEFT(A1,FIND("==",A1)-1)
But, its mainly return the text before first heading...

Comment: Please edit your question instead of posting comments. Before you do anything else here, please learn [ask]. Nobody wants to read a wall of comments to find out what your real problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
Sub Test()
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim s As String
    Dim pattn As String
    'Dim Match As MatchCollection
    Dim Match  As Object
    Dim vR() As Variant
    Dim i As Long, n As Long, k As Long
    Dim vSplit As Variant

    s = Range("a1")
    pattn = "(Heading[ ]{1,}\d{1,}[ :\w]{1,})"

    Set Match = GetRegEx(s, pattn)

    s = ReplaceRegEx(s, pattn, "mysplit")
    s = Replace(s, "=", "")
    vSplit = Split(s, " mysplit")
    n = UBound(vSplit)
    ReDim vR(1 To (n + 1) * 2 - 1)
    k = 1
    For i = 0 To n - 1
        vR(k) = vSplit(i)
        vR(k + 1) = Match.Item(i)
        k = k + 2
    Next i
    vR(UBound(vR)) = vSplit(n)
    Range("c1").Resize(1, UBound(vR)) = vR '<~~ content and Heading
    Range("c2").Resize(1, n + 1) = vSplit '<~~  contents
End Sub
Function GetRegEx(StrInput As String, strPattern As String) As Object
    Dim RegEx As Object

    'Set RegEx = New RegExp
    Set RegEx = CreateObject("VBscript.RegExp")
    With RegEx
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .MultiLine = True
        .Pattern = strPattern
    End With
    If RegEx.Test(StrInput) Then
        Set GetRegEx = RegEx.Execute(StrInput)
       'GetRegEx = RegEx.Replace(StrInput, strReplace)
    End If
End Function

Function ReplaceRegEx(StrInput As String, strPattern As String, strReplace)
    Dim RegEx As Object

    'Set RegEx = New RegExp
    Set RegEx = CreateObject("VBscript.RegExp")
    With RegEx
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .MultiLine = True
        .Pattern = strPattern
    End With
    If RegEx.Test(StrInput) Then
       ReplaceRegEx = RegEx.Replace(StrInput, strReplace)
    End If
End Function
```

### Result Image

[image]