# Replacing Values in parentheses with a Regular Expression Function

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I have a column with characters and numerical in parentheses. I would like to remove everything present in parentheses.

I used the formula `{"=RegExpReplace(H2,"\([^)]*\)","")"}` to remove numerical from the cell. I would like to automate this process because of the large data.

I have written the following module.

```
Sub RegexReplacingAPattern()
Dim stringOne As String
Dim regexOne As Object
Set regexOne = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
 
With regexOne
    regexOne.Pattern = "[\([^)]*\)]+"
    regexOne.Global = False
End With
    
End Sub
```

**Example input:**

```
CBL:NM_005188:c.1254C>G_p.F418L(0.0762,1116), MET:NM_000245:c.2888-42_2888del43_p.splice site 2888-42_2888del43(0.7125,2122)
```

**Example output:**

```
CBL:NM_005188:c.1254C>G_p.F418L, MET:NM_000245:c.2888-42_2888del43_p.splice site 2888-42_2888del43
```

Comment: What is the problem you're having?

Comment: The module I have written is not working the way I would like. And I am not sure the module is even correct or complete.

Comment: If there is a lot of data, it is faster to receive the data of the sheet as an array, modify the contents of the array, and enter the contents of the array again in the sheet without modifying the contents of the cells one by one. refer regexp [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61068939/how-to-split-excell-cell-into-multiple-column-based-on-heading-tag/61072655#61072655)

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Tester()
    RegexReplaceIt Range("F20:F26"), "\([^)]*\)"
End Sub


Sub RegexReplaceIt(rng As Range, pattern As String)
    Dim regexOne As Object, c As Range
    Set regexOne = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With regexOne
        regexOne.pattern = pattern
        regexOne.Global = True
    End With
    For Each c In rng.Cells
        c.Value = regexOne.Replace(c.Value, "")
    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, Tim, the module is working. I do have one more question, how can I add prompt to ask the user to add "Select a cell range:"
I appreciate your time. Thanks

Comment: https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/vba-to-select-range-with-inputbox